# How to assign a global char variable value to an array?

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in c++ and trying to code **Tic - Tac - Toe...**
i want to take input  from  the user in the form of numbers  if **player**
**1** hits a number say 1 replace it with **X** but it isn't working !!

```
 #include < iostream >      
 using  namespace   std;       
 char  player = 'X';      
char matrix [3] [3] = { '1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' , '6' , '7' , '8' ,'9'};      
void  Draw(){       
for (int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++ ){                              
for (int j=0 ; j<3 ; j++ ){      
        cout << matrix [i][j] << " ";      
    }           
      cout << endl ;          
}      
}      
void Input () {      
    char a;     
    cin >> a;      
    if ( a == 1 ) {      
        matrix [0] [0] = player;       //player 1 turn print X from         
                                       // char player='X';     
        }     
    else if(a==2){
        matrix[0][1]=player;
        }  
     else if(a==3){
        matrix[0][2]=player;
        } 

    else if(a==4){
        matrix[1][0]=player;
        }   
    else if(a==5){
        matrix[1][1]=player;
        }   
    else if(a==6){
        matrix[1][2]=player;
        }   
    else if(a==7){
        matrix[2][0]=player;
        }
    else if(a==8){
        matrix[2][1]=player;
        }   
    else if(a==9){
        matrix[2][2]=player;
        }
```

**Output is 1 not X**
can u please give me the answer!
many thanks.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: If you format your code more neatly with consistent indentation it is easier to follow the logic and that would probably help people to spot any errors.

Comment: why do u have spaces in cin

Comment: You know that `c i n` is not the same as `cin`? You can't have spaces in the middle of program statements.

Comment: sorry ...it was a problem in formatting code!!

Comment: I suggest you get a good book and work methodically through that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: If you are a beginner, start by reading [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), before you do anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't compare a number with character.
it should be a == '1'.
Rest is your logic.

Comment: actually following a you-tube tutorial...his code works fine but mine does not working!

Comment: @AliNawaz - Why not ask *him* for help then?

Comment: comparing a number with a character can make perfectly sense (a `char` is just a number), its just in this particular case that it is not what OP wants

Comment: I agree with ascii or any coded format, value comparison, but I said in regard to this question. Match by promotion doesn't work correctly on this question.

Comment: @Aconcagua, exactly. '1' != 1.